# Smarty setting nav href based on URL

Tags: php, templates, smarty

I'm working on a site which requires the nav links to smooth scroll to anchors on the home page, and the nav links to be linked to individual pages on all other pages. I've tried various tactics for achieving this to no avail. Here's some of the ways I've attempted this.

URLs are constructed with `.htaccess`. Home has no request URI as it is the index page of the site. `PUBLIC_URL` is set in a config file.

Check if `HTTP_HOST` is equal to `PUBLIC_URL`, and that no parameters are being passed for other pages.

```
{if $smarty.server.HTTP_HOST == $smarty.const.PUBLIC_URL && $smarty.server.REQUEST_URI == ''}
<a href="#locations">Our Locations <i class="ti-angle-down"></i></a></span>
{else}
<a href="{$public_url}locations">Our Locations <i class="ti-angle-down"></i></a></span>
{/if}
```

Checking if there are any params (logically doesn't work as `PUBLIC_URL` is a constant, and thus will always return false in this case).

```
{if $smarty.const.PUBLIC_URL == ''}
<a href="#locations">Our Locations <i class="ti-angle-down"></i></a></span>
{else}
<a href="{$public_url}locations">Our Locations <i class="ti-angle-down"></i></a></span>
{/if}
```

Going based off of the template being processed (logically doesn't work as the nav is contained in it's own template file).

```
{if $smarty.template == 'home.tpl'}
<a href="#locations">Our Locations <i class="ti-angle-down"></i></a></span>
{else}
<a href="{$public_url}locations">Our Locations <i class="ti-angle-down"></i></a></span>
{/if}
```

See if no request URI is present. Still returns false.

```
{if $smarty.server.REQUEST_URI === ''}
<a href="#locations">Our Locations <i class="ti-angle-down"></i></a></span>
{else}
<a href="{$public_url}locations">Our Locations <i class="ti-angle-down"></i></a></span>
{/if}
```

I've been stuck on this for a couple of hours, and have exhausted my search inquiries on Google, SO, and Smarty forums. Any direction will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, can't you just pass a variable to smarty in your php file when it's the home page?

```
$smarty->assign('this_is_the_home_page',true);
```

and then in the template

```
{if $this_is_the_home_page}
{$url="#locations"}
{else}
{$url=$public_url|cat:'locations'}
{/if}

<a href="{$url}">Our Locations <i class="ti-angle-down"></i></a></span>
```